# Compare int to NaN

Tags: javascript, titanium

Using Titanium, is there a way to compare a TextField's value to NaN (not a number)?

For example:

```
if (parseInt($.myTextField.value) == NaN)
```

In this example, it doesn't enter the *if statement*.  I've also tried with '===' to no success.

If I log the value converted to int it says "NaN"

```
Ti.API.info(parseInt($.myTextField.value));
```

Your input is appreciated!

Comment: Use `isNaN` native JS function!

Comment: Equality comparisons to `NaN` will always be `false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `isNaN` native JS function.  `===` to `NaN` will always be falsy.

Comment: @LightStyle yeah, you should have posted as answer, not comment. I just didn't feel like explaining that over comment.

Comment: I'm not here for rep :) anyway don't worry, it's how SO works! You don't have to explain nothing(there will be surely a lot of duplicates of this question anyway)

Comment: @GabCas: You should note that `isNaN()` performs a *toNumber* coercion on its parameter, so the results may not be what you'd expect, like `isNaN("foo"); // true` vs `isNaN(["23"]); // false`